# Syntactic vs Semantic interoperability in IoT

Tags: iot

What is semantic and syntactic interoperabilty on IoT, and what is the difference between them? I am reading papers, googling etc in order to understand what is syntactic and what is semantic interoperability in IoT, and what is the difference between them, but I am really confused, either beacause my background is too poor on this field or I cannot understand the small (?) boundary between those 2 words. Can you help with an example, or anything that could help me?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Taking a very concrete example: [LWM2M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMA_LWM2M) defines both a syntactical standard and adds many semantic standards on top.

The syntactical standard defines how to transfer data, i.e. how are strings, integers, floats arrays and structs are represented and transferred. This part of the standard does not care if you transfer temperature data, smart meter data, parking sensors data or whatever.

The semantical standard defines how e.g. a temperature sensor is represented. See [LWM2M Registry](http://www.openmobilealliance.org/wp/OMNA/LwM2M/LwM2MRegistry.html) under ID 3303 for details. You can find on that page semantic standards for different domains.

Another view to syntactical standard vs. semantical standard: JSON defines a syntactical standard, while a specific JSON Schema file defining the JSON for a temperature sensor would provide a semantic standard.